# Unable to start meeting with zoom SDK

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, zoom-sdk

I am new to zoom iOS sdk, I am able to successfully join meeting on zoom with iOS sdk but unable to start new meeting from iOS sdk.

```
// API User info for starting calls as API user.
static let userID = "gurpal@relinns.com"
static let userToken =  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOm51bGwsImlzcyI6ImRGZmdMWHA2UWUyWW92QWo2TzZPZkEiLCJleHAiOjE1OTI1NzQ1MjUsImlhdCI6MTU5MjU2OTEyNn0.35Gw_qTxcgpuQ51IVa4a4JalgqIQdi2HnpmviRcJ3PE"  //ZoomExternalApis.init().getUserToken(userId: "Gurpal@relinns.com")
```

I am using jwt token from zoom dashboard.
but when I start meeting with below code

```
// Start a Zoom meeting immediately.
func startMeeting(name: String = ZoomAPI.defaultName, number: Int = -1, password: String = "") {
    guard isAPIAuthenticated || isUserAuthenticated, let meetingService = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService() else { return }

    var paramDict: [String : Any] = [kMeetingParam_Username : name]

    if isAPIAuthenticated && !isUserAuthenticated {
        paramDict[kMeetingParam_UserID] = ZoomAPI.userID
        paramDict[kMeetingParam_UserToken] = ZoomAPI.userToken
    }

    if number != -1 {
        paramDict[kMeetingParam_MeetingNumber] = "\(number)"
    }

    if password.count > 0 {
        paramDict[kMeetingParam_MeetingPassword] = password
    }

    let returnValue = meetingService.startMeeting(with: paramDict)

    guard returnValue == MobileRTCMeetError_Success else {
        print("Zoom: Start meeting task failed, error code: \(returnValue.rawValue)")
        return
    }

    print("Zoom: Start meeting task completed.")
}
```

}

Then it gives me error "Unable to connect Make sure you have connected to the internet and your connection to zoom is not blocked by a firewall or proxy"
But everything is correct as I am also able to join meeting.